# Disable value and text in selectbox using javascript variable that is passed inside an ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, drop-down-menu, ejs

This is what my script defer code looks like

```
<script>
// parse the stored stringified item in json to able to use it in defer code
var item = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("itemValueTemp").value);
console.log(item);

// call function right on load of webpage to show instant quantity for a selected value in selectbox
handleQuantity();

var currentQty = 0;

function handleQuantity (){

    // get value of id category in selectbox and find the selected option 
    var categoryValue = $("#category").find('option:selected');

    // to get specific content of "value" attrib in selectbox
    var value = categoryValue.val();

    // find the variation array for the selected variation value using ,find and passing the var value
    var selectVariation = item.variations.find(x=>(x.name === value));
    currentQty = selectVariation.quantity;
    
}
</script>
```

This is what my ejs code for selectbox looks like

```
<select name="variation" onchange="handleQuantity();" id="category" class="form-control">
<% item.variations.forEach(function(variation){ %>
    <% if(currentQty > 0) {%>
        <option value="<%= variation.name %>"><%= variation.name %></option>
    <% } else { %>
        <option value="<%= variation.name %>" disabled><%= variation.name %></option>
    <% } %>
<% }) %>
</select>
```

This is the error that i receive is that currentQty is undefined

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY1e6.png)

Comment: you can't access your script variables like this. what you intend to do?

Comment: I want to disable the specific value in the selectbox when its current quantity or the variable currentQty is equal to or below zero i do not how to that, if you know a possible way, i'm all ears, thanks!

Comment: you can only access variables in ejs scriplet tags which you are passing in your render function. I see you are parsing some value from id **itemValueTemp** . What value it contains? Can you share your render code also the ejs part where you defined this **itemValueTemp** id?